# ASP Classic, update sql datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, asp-classic

I'm trying to do this update to my SQL table but no luck so far.

The datetime in my SQL is: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`.

When I use `now()`, the format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`.

So I change it to match:

```
new_now = month(now())&"/"&day(now())&"/"&year(now())&" "&time()
```

and here is my update SQL:

```
"UPDATE tblpo_po set purchase_status = '2', purchased_at = "&new_now&" where po_id = '"&request("po_number")&"' "
```

No luck so far.

error:

> Incorrect_syntax_near_'10' (which is not relevant at all anyway)

Any idea?

Comment: There is a sql injection vulnerability in the update statement. Po_number could be modified by the user to include sql commands. Using parameters would prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

found it, here is how: (http://p2p.wrox.com/classic-asp-basics/32475-asp-sql-server-datetime-field.html)

FUNCTION amDate(varDate)
    IF isNull(varDate) OR Trim(varDate) = "" OR varDate = "Null" THEN
       amDate = "Null"
    ELSE
       amDate = "'" & Month(DateValue(varDate)) & "/" & Day(DateValue(varDate)) & "/" & Year(DateValue(varDate)) & " " & TimeValue(varDate) & "'"
    END IF 
  END FUNCTION

Try this (single quotes not neccessary, the function puts these in there, its a good practice to always use triling semi colons):
"Update LOGS SET LastActionBy = " & amDate(NOW()) & " WHERE ID = 5;"

then it works.

ref: http://p2p.wrox.com/classic-asp-basics/32475-asp-sql-server-datetime-field.html

Answer (score 0):

Just need single quotes around your original date value. The "10" error was probably the hour of the time.

I would also suggest using parameters instead of sql string concatenation.